# How to remove 'route' object in Sitecore jss layout service api response?

Tags: sitecore-api, jss

When I get the data from `http://{domain.name}/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=[api-key]`

Then response is like {**sitecore**: {**context**:{something}, **route**:{something}}

But I don't want to include the route object if, in my custom layout service extension code some condition is not met.

Comment: @adam I have the same scenario to customize the output of route object. The customization needs to be done without touching the code of components. Could you please suggest which pipeline or code used for it.

Answer (score 3):

The most straightforward approach will likely be to extend and customize the `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Serialization.LayoutTransformer`, specifically, the `Transform(RenderedItem rendered)` method.

The default `LayoutTransformer` is declared via config in `/App_Config/Sitecore/LayoutService/Sitecore.LayoutService.Jss.config`.

You'll see the `jss` named configuration for Layout Service:

```
<config name="jss">
  <rendering type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Configuration.DefaultRenderingConfiguration, Sitecore.LayoutService">
    <placeholdersResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Placeholders.DynamicPlaceholdersResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService" />
    <itemSerializer type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.JssItemSerializer, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine" resolve="true">
      <AlwaysIncludeEmptyFields>true</AlwaysIncludeEmptyFields>
    </itemSerializer>
    <renderingContentsResolver type="Sitecore.LayoutService.ItemRendering.ContentsResolvers.RenderingContentsResolver, Sitecore.LayoutService">
      <IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>true</IncludeServerUrlInMediaUrls>
    </renderingContentsResolver>
  </rendering>
  <serialization type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.SerializationConfiguration, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine">
    <transformer type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.LayoutService.Serialization.LayoutTransformer, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine" resolve="true" />
  </serialization>
</config>
```

And within that named configuration is the `LayoutTransformer` declaration (`config/rendering/serialization/transformer`).

Lastly, a custom layout transformer may look something like below. Note that if the custom condition is met, then the `route` object will not be in the final output.

```
public class CustomLayoutTransformer : LayoutTransformer    
{
    public CustomLayoutTransformer(IPlaceholderTransformer placeholderTransformer) : base(placeholderTransformer)
    {
    }

    public override dynamic Transform(RenderedItem rendered)
    {
        var baseResult = base.Transform(rendered);

        if (myCustomCondition)
        {
            dynamic newResult = new ExpandoObject();
            newResult.sitecore = new
            {
                baseResult.context
            };
            return newResult;
        }

        return baseResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this way also but the thing is that I am not able to get the route object, but I am able to get the context object. My requirement is with route object.

Comment: Your question said you want to remove the `route` object, the `CustomLayoutTransformer` code snippet provided above will do that. Is there something else you need to accomplish?

Comment: Okay, I understood now @Thanks a lot. I just understood the code as present in different pipeline.